# How to create an SFTP login for each website (/ home) with NGINX?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx, sftp

I need to create an SFTP login that can write in public_html and that Wordpress can also install and remove applications.

By passing the site permissions to nginx (user and group), and using FS_Method in wp-config.php, Wordpress is able to update, remove and install plugins.
When passing permissions to loginsite (user) and group (www), SFTP works, but Wordpress stops working.

In Apache this would be possible, now with NGINX, do I need to link something with the NGINX group to create SFTP?

```
echo "Insert your domain:"
read vhost

#Security directory home vhost without shell
chown root:root /var/www
chmod 751 /var/www
groupadd www
useradd --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin --groups www --home /var/www/$vhost $vhost
mkdir /var/www/$vhost
chown root:www /var/www/$vhost
chmod 751 /var/www/$vhost
mkdir /var/www/$vhost/public_html
chown $vhost:www /var/www/$vhost/public_html
chmod 751 /var/www/$vhost/public_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring WP:

You can fill in the FTP credential prompt every time, or put the following to wp-config.php file.

```
// Path to your key files, if you got multiple key files remember to
// use the right key here.
define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa');

// The SFTP user goes here.
define('FTP_USER', 'user');

// This was a culprit for me once, didn't work without it.
// Possible values: "direct", "ssh2", "ftpext", or "ftpsockets".
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

// Hostname, define a custom port here if in use.
define('FTP_HOST', 'example.com:73000');
```

Also, might need to have libssh2-php installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install libssh2-php
```

After install restart your webserver

```
$ service nginx restart
```